# C# : Editing/saving/Sending a docx document

Tags: c#, .net-core, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

Been strugling with a lot of problems. Using OpenXML on a ASP.NET Core server, I want to create a new docx document based on a template one. Once this document is fully saved, I want it to be sent to my client so he can download it directly. Here's my code :

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Consultant consultant)
    {
            using (Stream templateStream = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.templateDossierTech))
            using (WordprocessingDocument template =
                WordprocessingDocument.Open(templateStream, false))
            {

                string fileName = environment.WebRootPath + @"\Resources\"+ consultant.FirstName + "_" + consultant.LastName + ".docx";
                WordprocessingDocument dossierTechniqueDocument =
                    WordprocessingDocument.Create(fileName,
                        WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
                foreach (var part in template.Parts)
                {
                    dossierTechniqueDocument.AddPart(part.OpenXmlPart, part.RelationshipId);
                }

                var body = dossierTechniqueDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                var paras = body.Elements();

                foreach (var para in paras)
                {
                    foreach (var run in para.Elements())
                    {
                        foreach (var text in run.Elements())
                        {
                            if (text.InnerText.Contains("{{prenom}}"))
                            {
                                var t = new Text(text.InnerText.Replace("{{prenom}}", consultant.FirstName));
                                run.RemoveAllChildren<Text>();
                                run.AppendChild(t);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                dossierTechniqueDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                dossierTechniqueDocument.Close();
                var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                {
                    FileName = consultant.FirstName + "_" + consultant.LastName + ".docx",
                    Inline = true
                };

                Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

                Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
                return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName),"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document","Dossier Technique");
        }
    }
```

As a first look, it looks like is saving well but when I try to open it on word, it says that it is corrupted for some reason.
That's the same problem when I try to send it. Once it's sent my client doesn't download it (Ajax query).
Do anyone of you have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: It's not clear what you expect the code to be doing... Why would you not simply make a copy of the "template" file then edit the copy? Also, what *file extension" does this template file have? Trouble-shooting this is almost impossible for us since we don't have the original file or your entire solution. If you don't want to copy the file, my recommendation would be to use the "Compare" function of the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to compare the original with a result of your code in order to track down what's going wrong (how the two differ).

Comment: But this is what I'm doing @CindyMeister . I'm copying the content of template into dossierTechniqueDocument (which are both .docx)

Comment: No, that's not what I was suggesting: Copy the **file** before opening it for editing using the Open XML SDK. You *think* you're copying the "template", but something is going wrong. I suspect it may have to do with the line `dossierTechniqueDocument.AddPart(part.OpenXmlPart, part.RelationshipId);` - a problem with the Relationships...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function which creates a document from a template:

```
static void GenerateDocumentFromTemplate(string inputPath, string outputPath)
    {
        MemoryStream documentStream;
        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(inputPath))
        {
            documentStream = new MemoryStream((int)stream.Length);
            CopyStream(stream, documentStream);
            documentStream.Position = 0L;
        }

        using (WordprocessingDocument template = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentStream, true))
        {
            template.ChangeDocumentType(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = template.MainDocumentPart;
            mainPart.DocumentSettingsPart.AddExternalRelationship("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/attachedTemplate",
               new Uri(inputPath, UriKind.Absolute));

            mainPart.Document.Save();
        }


        File.WriteAllBytes(outputPath, documentStream.ToArray());
    }
```