# Openxml SDK CreateFromTemplate example

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I am trying to understand the openXML sdk a little better. I see that there is a "CreateFromTemplate" method, that is supposed to create a MemoryStream from a given office template file (XLST in my case). I am curious how I can access the stream to return a file stream for download. The documentation is kind of light on this one, and I have not been able to find any examples dealing with the CreaetFromTemplate method.

thanks

Comment: actually it is not XSLT template, it is MSWord template (.dotx or .dotm)

Comment: [how to create document from template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52894075/c-sharp-editing-saving-sending-a-docx-document/52931956#52931956)

Comment: Thanks Michael. Sorry for the late reply I was troubleshooting a different issue with the OpenXML sdk on .net core.
I am a bit confused, because the CreateFromTemplate method is available from the SPreadSheetDocument class.

Comment: I guess I wasn't aware of that method in SDK, always used the one I linked. So the library method should work for you then.